# How to set the default value for media entity in content type in a user friedly way?

Tags: media

In a new content type (Drupal 9) I have an Entity Reference field for Media (Image). I already chose and saved a default media entity in the field settings.

Unfortunately when creating a new node of this content type a user needs to remove the default media entity first before being able to upload his/her image. Since this seems not very user friedly I wonder whether there is a way to avoid this.

For example in a field that is an Entity Reference for Image (not Media) a set default image appears only if the user does not upload an own image. Here the user does not have to first remove the default image. I am looking for a way to accomplish this for the Entity Reference field for Media, but I can't find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: The media field is working as intended, it is actually the image field that is misbehaving: All entity reference fields store the default value in the database (which makes it null-able and exposable to e.g. JSON API), only the image field computes a fallback value. The behavior you describe in the admin UI is a side-effect of that bug, so I don't think there is any setting or module to "force the media field to be buggy".

Comment: Hmm, I think you would have to implement this behaviour yourself. You could allow users to provide no value and in `hook_node_presave()`, add the value if the field is empty.